# Create a chat module in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a chat system on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380851/how-to-make-a-chat-system-on-iphone)

I have created a tab bar application there I want to create a chat module.
Basically, I want a chat module when we start chat with my some of friend and after chat is completed all the chat video will be stored in my local app.

I need one module, from there I will create a chat module and store in the local app. Does somebody know how to create chat functionality have any related code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you know about socket programming? Will you be writing the server software yourself, or are you using something that already exists?

You could take a look at the [CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) for some information on the networking side of things.