# iPhone chat functionality

Tags: iphone, chat

i want to implement a chat functionality between two iOS devices.Please suggest me some libraries for the same.I went for XMPP but code is not available for that on repository.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a chat system on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380851/how-to-make-a-chat-system-on-iphone)

Comment: See also [iphone xmpp chat client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989921/iphone-xmpp-chat-client) and [chat application implementation in iPhone os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990233/chat-application-implementation-in-iphone-os)

Answer (score 1):

You visit tutorial by [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/). [Part1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) and [Part2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2). In this tutorial he has explained how to use webservice and PushNotification for chat kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [Scringo](http://www.scringo.com). It's SDK offers chat between your app users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using push notifications?

You could use a service like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) so you don't have to roll your own push server, and they provide a pretty comprehensive [iOS Framework](http://urbanairship.com/docs/airship_lib.html) which you could use to take advantage of their services.

You would of course still need some way of tracking who was talking with who so there would need to be some work on your part to build the necessary intermediary software/API, although this should be a pretty trivial task since all you'd need to do is keep a record of each of the device tokens in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

XMPP is still alive.. A [newer version](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/WhatsNewInV3) also came up...

You can download [Version 2](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) directly here

To download [Version 3](https://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/%20xmppframework) you have to download and install Mercurial repository and download it running this hg clone on the Mac Terminal...

Comment: Version 3 link is broken, can you please check and update if possible!